# Wordpress API not returning anything until I use rest_ensure_response

Tags: wordpress, response, jwt, wp-api

I have a JWT plugin for authentication but when I make call to `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` it doesn't return anything, so I tried to return the response from **rest_ensure_response** function and it returned the response correctly. It was also the problem with other plugins also so I had to change all of those. Is there any way I can do this without having to change the plugin code?

**Previously return statememnt (return blank)**

```
return apply_filters('jwt_auth_token_before_dispatch', $data, $user);
```

**Updated return statememnt (return correct response)**

```
$return = apply_filters('jwt_auth_token_before_dispatch', $data, $user);
return rest_ensure_response($return);
```

**Function Used**

```
rest_ensure_response
```

**Plugin URL**
https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth

**WP_Error is also returning blank.**

**PS: I tested the plugin on a local installation of wordpress and it is working fine without changing anything. Now sure what is the issue. I have also turned off wp_debug.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code I was using `rest_request_after_callbacks` filter so I have to edit the callback function. Now it is working fine.